# Getting ID from the table blade.php to other blade.php error Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table view in which I have a view button and redirect to another page carrying the id of the row that has been clicked.

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
   <?php $hold=0; ?>
   @if(!empty($users))
    @foreach($users as $user)
      @if($user->role == 3)
       <?php $hold++; ?>
        <td class="py-1">{{ $user->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->name }} </td>
        <td>{{ $user->Zone }} </td>
        <td>{{ $user->Purok }}</td>
        <td> Wala pa sa database </td>
        <td>
          <div class="template-demo">
            <button type="button" onclick="location.href=' {{ route ('SupAd.View_PL_Accnt/'.$user->id) }}'"  class="btn btn-outline-info btn-icon-text">
             <i class="ti-search btn-icon-append"></i>View
              </button>
            </div>
         </td>
    </tr>
    @endif
    @endforeach
    <?php  if($hold == 0){
      echo "<p><font color=red size='4pt'>No purok leader can be found</font></p>";
    }
    ?>
    @endif
```

I have here my code on web.php route

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'SupAd_Purok_Leader_Account', 'middleware'=>['isSupAd', 'auth', 'PreventBackHistory']], function (){
 Route::get('View_PL_Accnt', [SupAdController::class, 'View_PL_Accnt'])->name('SupAd.View_PL_Accnt/{id}'); });
```

And I got the error:

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
> Route [SupAd.View_PL_Accnt/3] not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are placing the route parameter in the wrong place. Try this:

```
Route::get('View_PL_Accnt/{id}', [SupAdController::class, 'View_PL_Accnt'])->name('SupAd.View_PL_Accnt'); });
```

The name is used to call a route using the `route` helper. You can give the url parameters to the route helper in an array. Inside your blade file use:

```
{{ route ('SupAd.View_PL_Accnt', [$user->id]) }}
```

Comment: Try changing the route name to something more clear. So route `{{ route ('test', [$user->id]) }}` in the blade file and `Route::get('View_PL_Accnt/{id}', [SupAdController::class, 'View_PL_Accnt'])->name('test'); });` in the routing

Answer (score 0):

you can change routes like

```
Route::get('View_PL_Accnt/{id}', [SupAdController::class, 'View_PL_Accnt'])->name('SupAd.View_PL_Accnt'); });
```

And change the button on click event

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='{!! route('SupAd.View_PL_Accnt', [$user->id]) !!}'"  class="btn btn-outline-info btn-icon-text">
             <i class="ti-search btn-icon-append"></i>View
              </button>
```